# MAX Function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Name, 
       max(if(location=2,value,' ')) as '#1', 
       max(if(location=2,value,' ')) as '#2' 
FROM value;
```

In the above query the MAX() returns a string value. SO how do I return a int/decimal value.

Comment: Please correct your question's title. What about the MAX function in MySQL? BTW I hope Emilia Clarke doesn't mind you impersonating her.

Comment: Surely the above query is not even valid? Field names are not delimited by `'`, for a start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAX()` returns the same datatype as the field it acts upon.

In your query you're saying if the location is 2 then `value` else `' '`, which is an empty string set.  Implicit conversion rules dictate how disparate datatypes will be handled, in this case a string begets a string.

You don't specify what datatype your `value` field is in your table, but assuming it's an int/decimal you'd just need to give your `ELSE` a different datatype... be that `0` or `NULL` it's up to you.

Also you should include `Name` in a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I did give a column name to the value set. (The column contains the int values). But the output was ""BLOB"". 
****No output of values but only it shows BLOB******